# Store CLLocation Manager Values in Device swift

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

I'm building an app that sends (every x seconds) to an API the location values with some extra values (session, ID, etc) that is working nice (see here [Update CLLocation Manager on another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39757134/update-cllocation-manager-on-another-method)). But for improved feature, we are considering the device can lost (for some amount of time) internet connection. So I need to temporary store all values and when reconnected send them again to the API.

I'm considering several ways to do it:

- Core Data (difficult implementation)
- Realm (very little experience)
- NSDisctionary

Can anyone suggest (and show how, if possible) the best way to implement this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store a some of non-sensitive values (such as a password), I suggest to use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults), you can easily use it like a dictionary:

*Note: Swift 2 Code.*

For example:

```
    // shared instance (singleton)
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    // **storing**:
    let myString = "my string"
    userDefaults.setObject(myString, forKey: "kMyString")

    let myInt = 101
    userDefaults.setInteger(myInt, forKey: "kMyInt")

    let myBool = true
    userDefaults.setBool(myBool, forKey: "kMyBool")

    userDefaults.synchronize()

    // **retrieving**:
    //use optional binding for objects to check if it's nil
    if let myRetrievedString = userDefaults.objectForKey("kMyString") as? String {
        print(myRetrievedString)
    } else {
        // if it's nil
        print("there is now value for key: kMyString")
    }

    // if there is no value for key: kMyInt, the output should be zero by default
    let myRetrievedInt = userDefaults.integerForKey("kMyInt")

    // if there is no value for key: kMyBool, the output should be false by default
    let myRetrievedBool = userDefaults.boolForKey("kMyBool")
```

Comment: TY @Ahmad. That was my first choice and thinking. But we can be using this app for sea navigation (not sure about how long can a trip take, could take hours!). Wouldn't be that to much for store it?

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510123/is-there-any-limit-in-storing-values-in-nsuserdefaults)
I hope the answer helped :)

Comment: You are the man! TY. I will give it a try and put answered if ok!

Comment: BTW a little extra help; How should I increment values (of the key(s))? The values are always updating, and I need to build a route/course. Not sure if I explained myself well

Comment: well, if I understand it right, you don't have to generate a new key for a new value, instead, add all of them in an array -for example- and set the array as a value for the same key each time, setting an object on the same key replaces the new value. Hope that's what you are asking about

Comment: That's it!So the structure will be something like this: array([lat => 123, lon => 456, timeStamp => 01:00],  [lat => 789, lon => 444, timeStamp => 02:00]) and so on

Comment: in this case you should use a dictionary, or store each value on separated keys.
Note: I recommend to use CLLocation to store lat and lng in one value

Comment: That's what I asked in first time :-)  You are right in your note about the lat and lon.

Answer (score 0):

Tadaaaaaa:

```
func arrayOfDictionaries() {
        var offline:[[String:AnyObject]] = []
        offline.append(["LATITUDE: ": userLocation.coordinate.latitude, "LONGITUDE: ": userLocation.coordinate.longitude, "SPEED: ": userLocation.speed])

        NSUserDefaults().setObject(offline, forKey: "offLine")

        if let offLinePositions = NSUserDefaults().arrayForKey("offLine") as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
            //print(offLinePositions)  


            for item in offLinePositions {
                print(item["LATITUDE: "]! as! NSNumber)  // A, B
                print(item["LONGITUDE: "]! as! NSNumber)  // 19.99, 4.99
                print(item["SPEED: "]! as! NSNumber)  // 1, 2
            }
        }

    }
```